# error occur during run the program of node.js

Tags: node.js

nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2

- nodemon demo.js

Comment: Q: did you perchance run `npm install -g nodemon`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to install node modules - run `npm install`  in the root of the project. Otherwise you may have to install nodemon

`npm install -g nodemon`